# How to do the image on the right/lef comes to the centre when user scroll

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have One big image in the centre and 2 images showing slightly on the left and the right. 
When the user scrolls, How to do  the image on the right comes to the centre ...?

Answer (score 1):

In delegate method:

```
scrollViewDidScroll:
```

add code lice this:

```
self.rightImage.center = CGPointMake(self.imageCenter.center.x, self.imageCenter.center.y);
```